# How Can I Make an MXML Variable Bindable in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, bindable

Is it possible to use the Bindable compiler setting when using mxml?

I've got a string that I want to make bindable:

```
<mx:String id="myString">My Text</mx:String>
```

I could make it bindable in Actionscript, like this:

```
[Bindable]
var myString:String = "My Text";
```

But, I'd like to use MXML in my situation.

I tried:

```
<mx:Metadata>
[Bindable]
</mx:Metadata>
<mx:String id="myString">My Text</mx:String>
```

But it threw a lot of warnings-- other classes were already marked bindable in my App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to bind to your mxml variable without any changes? As far as I know all MXML tags are bindable by default.

Comment: Thank you Constantiner. You're right they are bindable by default. I just tried it and it worked. Thank you!